# Read QR Code from still/static image

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, qr-code, cidetector

I am working on an app where I have to read QR Code from still image. Following is the code that I have used to read the QR Code:

```
CIImage *ciimage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:[getRotatedImage CGImage]];

NSDictionary *detectorOptions = @{ CIDetectorAccuracy : CIDetectorAccuracyHigh };
            CIDetector *faceDetector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeQRCode context:nil options:detectorOptions];

 NSArray *features = [faceDetector featuresInImage:ciimage];
            CIQRCodeFeature *faceFeature;
            for(faceFeature in features)
            {
                NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",faceFeature.messageString];
                break;
            }
```

This code is working fine for some QR Code but some time it is not working with still image and return blank array. I have searched a lot and also see the Apple forum they have also described the same code that I have used. I am also attaching the image that is not decoded.[image] Please any body has any type of information regarding this then share with me. It would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the position of QRCode always in left-bottom corner?

Comment: No @YunCHEN: it is not neccesary, it could be on top left corner, top right corner etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I just tested your image locally, and I can confirm, the QR code isn't read. I believe your problem is the QR code. It seems that maybe the logo is interfering with the CIDetector. I replaced your QR Code with another QR code, and it worked.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"qr3"];
    CIImage *ciimage = [CIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f)];

    NSDictionary *detectorOptions = @{ CIDetectorAccuracy : CIDetectorAccuracyHigh };
    CIDetector *faceDetector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeQRCode context:nil options:detectorOptions];

    NSArray *features = [faceDetector featuresInImage:ciimage];
    CIQRCodeFeature *faceFeature;
    for(faceFeature in features) {
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",faceFeature.messageString];
        NSLog(@"Found feature: %@", str);
        break;
    }
```

This logs: `Found feature: http://en.m.wikipedia.org`

[image]